Enable virtualization on an existing Azure VM
I have a AZURE VM running Windows Server 2022 size standard E8as V4 with 8 vcpus and 64 GiB.
The problem I have is I trying to install wsl but I am getting 'please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS'.
I have tried to change this by installing via powershell, but didn't work. How do I change this in AZURE front end?

Try How to enable virtualization in Azure VM

This question is similar to: Hyper-V within Azure virtual machine. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

your instance type doesn't supported nested virtualization https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes/memory-optimized/eav4-series?tabs=sizebasic
